# Concat sub-arrays mongodb aggregation

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

Supposing I have the following document:

```
   {
      "_id": "101",
      "animalArray": [['dog'], ['lizard', 'lion']],
      "array_b":[10,20]
   }
```

What is a straightforward way to concatenate `['lizard', 'lion']` and `[10,20]` in order to get this output:

```
{
    "_id": "101",
    "animalArray": [['dog'], ['lizard', 'lion', 10, 20]]
}
```

`array_b` needs to be concatenated only to second sub-array.
Using `$concatArrays` and `$project`, I could not get this result.

Comment: Why didn't you concat all to `animalArray` like `['dog', 'lizard', 'lion', 10, 20]` ? What criteria drives you to get `[['dog'], ['lizard', 'lion', 10, 20]]` ? Is that `array_b` needs to be concatenated only to second element in `animalArray` for all docs?

Comment: Yes, that's right. array_b needs to be concatenated only to second element in animalArray for all docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation query :

**Query 1:**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      animalArray: {
        $map: {
          input: "$animalArray",
          in: {
            $cond: [ /** Check if it's first element in 'animalArray' array */
              { $eq: ["$$this", { $arrayElemAt: ["$animalArray", 1] }] },
              { /** If Yes, merge 1st element with elements of 'array_b' array */
                $reduce: {
                  input: "$array_b",
                  initialValue: "$$this",
                  in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", ["$$this"]] }
                },
              },
              "$$this" /** If No, Just pass it on*/
            ],
          },
        },
      },
    },
  }
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ebLCb5m1Ppu)

**Query 2:** You might not need to use `$map` to loop through 'animalArray' if it contains only two elements as first query is more of dynamically doing this.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      animalArray: 1,
      mergedArray: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$array_b",
          initialValue: { $arrayElemAt: ["$animalArray", 1] },
          in: { $concatArrays: ["$$value", ["$$this"]] },
        },
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $project: {
      animalArray: {
        $concatArrays: [
          [{ $arrayElemAt: ["$animalArray", 0] }],
          ["$mergedArray"],
        ],
      },
    },
  },
]);
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/YfKwtxK2qT-)

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than 2 elements in animalArray, so whoami's answer is probably the best. But if you have only 2 elements in, you can do it in a single $project stage, with $concatArrays. Here's the query :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      "animalArray": {
        $concatArrays: [
          [
            {
              $arrayElemAt: [
                "$animalArray",
                0
              ]
            }
          ],
          [
            {
              $concatArrays: [
                {
                  $arrayElemAt: [
                    "$animalArray",
                    1
                  ]
                },
                "$array_b"
              ]
            }
          ],

        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

You can test it [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/m815D3DySH3)

Comment: Thank you @matthPen